# Angular components, controller not loading

Tags: angularjs

I have the following angular:

```
angular.module("app.components", []);
angular.module("app", [
    "app.components"
]);

angular.module("app.components")
    .component('testWidget', {
        templateUrl: '/Widgets/TestWidget/Templates/TestWidget.template.html',
        bindings: {
            something: "="
        },
        controller: function () {
            var ctrl = this;
            // ctrl has nothing on it
        }
    });

<div ng-app="app">
    <test-widget something="Shoopy"></test-widget>
</div>
```

but the `something` is not part of the object (`this`) in the controller. what have i missed?

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: No error, it's just that ctrl.something does not exist?

Answer (score 1):

two-way binding (expects a parent scope property to watch for value changes):

```
bindings: {
    something: "="
}
```

A parent controller would need to set the property:

```
$scope.Shoopy = "hello world"
```

For parameter bindings use the following:

string value binding:

```
bindings: {
    something: "@"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you forgot `controllerAs` since you're using `this` instead of `$scope`

try this

```
angular.module("app.components")
    .component('testWidget', {
        templateUrl: '/Widgets/TestWidget/Templates/TestWidget.template.html',
        bindings: {
            something: "="
        },
        controllerAs: "ctrl",
        controller: function () {
            var ctrl = this;
            // ctrl has nothing on it
        }
    });
```